# Measuring time in C gives wrong result

Tags: c, time, timeval

I am trying to measure time in C in microseconds. I tried this code, but the value `time_passed` is a huge number, instead of 0 (or 1).

```
   struct timeval start;
   settimeofday(&start,NULL);
   struct timeval stop;
   settimeofday(&stop,NULL);
   unsigned long long int time_passed = 
       (stop.tv_sec-start.tv_sec)*1000000 + (stop.tv_usec - start.tv_usec);
   printf("time passed: %llu us\n",time_passed);
```

Comment: There is not statement between your start and stop. Only a declaration.

Comment: He means there is nothing to compute between `start` and `stop`

Comment: But maybe that was the intention.

Comment: You are not checking return values of functions. It looks like you don't care whether your calls sucseed or fail.

Comment: @n.m.: But in the true spirit of C programming, the code gets to the end as quickly as possible!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are calling `settimeofday()` when you should be calling `gettimeofday()`!